# Are ExtJS7 events able to detect Server-Side-Events (WebFlux)?

Tags: spring-boot, extjs, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring Boot with ExtJS7... I have a process where the user uploads a text file (CSV) into the database.  This csv gets parsed and populates some tables in MySql.

What I am curious about is whether or not [ExtJS custom events](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/guides/core_concepts/events.html) can pick up **Server Side Events** via Webflux.  The documentation deals mainly with how ExtJS components handle events and the wiring within.

My upload process isn't something that done very often so I'd like to avoid constantly polling or keeping a websocket open.  Currently in the existing app, the user has to manually click a button in the UI to kick off the processing of the text file.

What I'd like to do is have the server push updates (overall status and % complete) to the browser while the CSV file is processing.

I've seen a few plugin examples for older versions of ExtJS that probably aren't going to help.  I saw a post [here on mykong](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-webflux-server-sent-events-example/) that describes how to do it in generic JavaScript, but I'd like to get an idea of the preferred way of doing it in ExtJS currently via the modern toolkit.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If it still helps: We managed to integrate ExtJS with SignalR, but the socket is almost always open. We did not use ExtJS custom events, other that the one that add listeners to the signalR connection

Comment: Still looking for a solution... It's for a nice-to-have feature...  I'll probably just implement an ajax refresh on a timer if I don't find anything...